# How to find similar values in two arrays and pass to the new position

Tags: android, arrays

I searched for my problem on StackOverflow. But This problem is not the same as them. I have two arrays. The first array has too many words.  The second array has custom words that user inputs. My purpose is; I want to search for similar values but when I find the similar value, It passes to next value of the second array. How can ı do it?

Example ;

> first array elements; all words of one language
>
> second array elements ; " cat ", "dog"
>
> result array; " category",   "dogde"

Here is my code ;

```
 for (String s: second_array
         ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < first_array.size(); i++) {
            if (first_array.get(i).toString().contains(s)){
                result_array.add(first_array.get(i).toString());

            }
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j <result_array.size() ; j++) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: " + result_array.get(j) + "  "+ result_array.size());
    }
```

if This code runs , I get too many values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `break` the `for` of first_array, but this only get the first similar word:

```
for (int i = 0; i < first_array.size(); i++) {
    if (first_array.get(i).toString().contains(s)){
        result_array.add(first_array.get(i).toString());
        //Add this line
        break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: To put the `"There is no such word"` if not found a similar word, your code it should look like this:

```
for (String s: second_array) {
    boolean isFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < first_array.size(); i++) {
        if (first_array.get(i).toString().contains(s)){
            result_array.add(first_array.get(i).toString());
            isFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!isFound) result_array.add("There is no such word");
}

for (int j = 0; j <result_array.size() ; j++) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: " + result_array.get(j) + "  "+ result_array.size());
}
```

Comment: oh. Thanks, my friend. It works perfectly. I searched for 4 days. By the way; I want to the little bit a different question. İf first array has not contained like the second item how to set "There is no such word"it to second array ?

Comment: Below the `for` of `first_array` add `result_array.add("There is no such word")`

Comment: This is not my other problem's answer. I asked if first array has not similar value of second array. How to set "There is no such word" to result array ?

Comment: When the `for` of your `first_array` is finish, use this line of code: `result_array.add("There is no such word");`

Comment: Duke this time , when For Loop found value. result_array is adding "There is no such word" same time with value. By the way if first array can not find, it works. I want  to same time if  first_array is contain throw to result_array. İf first_array is not contain throw ""There is no such word" "  to result_array. Second array length must be equal to result array lenght.

Comment: Ops! I will edit the answer and add the solution for your second problem.

Comment: Wow. I can never think like this. Thanks your helping.